# Accessing SOAP API with Perl. Long Int -problems?

Tags: perl, api, soap, wsdl, long-integer

I have at my hands a SOAP API that has plenty of functionality, but from which I only need two methods: adding user to a database and deleting user from a database.

Currently I am locked to Perl as the language for this task.

Because deleting a user takes in as the only parameter the "id" of the user (not "userId" as in username), I need to define it myself rather than relying on MySQL's auto_increment.

Relevant parts from the WSDL:

```
<xs:element name="saveLocalUserEx">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="user" nillable="true" type="ns2:LocalUser"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="requestingUser" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/></xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="LocalUser">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="dbData" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="description" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="displayName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="domainName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="enabled" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="firstName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="lastName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="loginId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="loginPasswordHash" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="loginPasswordHashType" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="preOrSelfProvisioned" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DEFAULT_PASSWORD_HASH_TYPE" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PKCS5_REVERSIBLE_HASH_TYPE" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SHA1_NON_REVERSIBLE_HASH_TYPE" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="STR_DEFAULT_ADMIN_NAME" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="STR_DEFAULT_DOMAIN" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="STR_DEFAULT_SPONSOR_NAME" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here are (relevant parts) of the code I first wrote.

```
my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    ->uri($uri)
    ->proxy($proxy);

sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {
    return 'abc' => 'abc';
    }

my $test_id = 1515;

# Preparing data for API query for saving the new user.
my $data = SOAP::Data->name("LocalUser" => 
    \SOAP::Data->value(
    SOAP::Data->name("loginId" => $new_username),
    SOAP::Data->name("enabled" => true),
    SOAP::Data->name("domainName" => $domainname),
    SOAP::Data->name("loginPasswordHash" => $hash),
    SOAP::Data->name("id" => $test_id),
    SOAP::Data->name("description" => 'Guest User Account generated on: ' . localtime()),
    SOAP::Data->name("displayName" => 'Guest')
    )
 );

my $som = $soap->saveLocalUserEx($data);
print Dumper $som->result();
```

It almost does the job. In the matter of fact; API accepts this query, result is success and a new user is generated. The problem is, that id field in the database is still MySQL auto_incremented, and not 1515 I tried to give it this time. Then I started thinking that maybe I need to type the parameter explicitly to long, because wsdl states the type for id is xs:long.

I've tried modifying my code with:

```
SOAP::Data->type('xs:long')->name("id" => $test),
```

and

```
SOAP::Data->type('long')->name("id" => $test),
```

But these didn't help. API query succeeds, but id is not made to 1515.

Do you guys have any idea how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: I guess the other side does not want you to set the user ID. The field is nillable after all. I believe there are some more methods that you have not shown here for selecting users. That's where the ID is needed to identify a user. But if you want to add one, they are relying on the auto increment. That's also why it sends the new ID back in the result.

Comment: In the matter of fact, ID is not sent back in the result. It would solve everything, if it was. :) I just happen to have access to the MySQL database itself, even though the system and API I'm using is a proprietary system and I can't really modify or check that out at all. In MySQL I have been able to verify that the id column is only auto_incremented and my orders about custom ID's are not taken into account.

Comment: What system are we talking about? Can you disclose the name?

Comment: Well, the system is Enterasys Netsight. It's very hard to acquire documentation of it without access to their extranet.

Comment: I was wondering, might this problem have something to do with namespace declarations, which I'm not really doing at all?

Comment: That could be the case. I suggest you tinker your own request by hand with namespaces and try it using http://www.soapui.org/. You could also consider trying SOAP::WSDL. I use that for a couple of projects.